# How to make windows of new folders open in my size?

Tags: macos, finder, folders, customization

In OS X 10.8.2, I create a new folder by right-clicking in the Finder and selecting *New Folder*. When I open this folder, the size of the window is not the size of the foremost window. The window size inherited by the new folder is always the system default window size, and apparently can not be changed by any means.

Is there a preference, possibly through Terminal, to have the windows of newly created folders open in my preferred window size?

Comment: When you say folder size, you're referring to the size of new Finder windows that show you the contents of a folder, correct?

Comment: I'm a bit confused too. New folders open to the size of whatever the size of your frontmost window is set to. New finder windows open to the whatever the size of the last closed window was.

Comment: I'm a bit confused too. New folders open to the size of whatever the size of your frontmost window is set to.                                                   NOT TRUE if you open a new window with New finder windows open to the whatever the size of the last closed window was.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly use column view and have removed all folders except the home folder from favorites, so the root folder of most windows is `~` or `/`. When the default dimensions or view options for them change, I reset them by running this script with [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/).

```
tell application "Finder"
    if number of windows is 0 then return
    tell Finder window 1
        set toolbar visible to false
        set sidebar width to 0
        set statusbar visible to false
        set current view to column view
        set bounds to {474, 250, 1318, 750}
        tell its column view options
            set shows icon to false
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

[FinderMinder](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/labs/) watches what windows you open and changes their dimensions. The windows appear at the previous position for a split second though.

[image]

Comment: @Ranta Thank you for the links - I'll look into them for sure (sorry for intruding). Do you know of a app or script that makes every new window open to a size that is just enough to view everything displayed in it? Maybe the width can be left standard....

Answer (score 1):

I finally came up with a nearly perfect solution based on Lauri Ranta’s script.

1. I modified the code slightly.
2. I did include some additional actions in Automator.
3. I called up the AppleScript code in Automator.
4. I saved the Automator script as “create new folder”.

<<< Not enough points to show Image of script >>>

In Service Preferences I activated “create new folder”, and assigned the keystroke <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>.

Keying <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> in the Finder now creates a new folder with the characteristics set up in the AppleScript.

I could assign <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> in Service Preferences to “create new folder”, but it did not replace the OS X default action of Cmd-Shift-N.

I like to hear from anybody who can get <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> to work with “create new folder”.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why not upload you image to another image hosting service and link to it? Then let me know in a comment "@bassplayer7", or flag your post and someone should be able to edit it in for you.