# How to fix Cover Flow size behaviour?

Tags: finder, icon, display

The resizing behaviour of Finder Cover Flow kinds of annoy me...

The size of the icons in the Cover Flow area is HUGE, while the list stays small at the bottom.

Moving the slider to make the Cover Flow area smaller works...
Until you open another folder.
Then, depending on some strange logic, you will get the HUGE icons again, or will stay with a smaller size.

But when I make a little bigger the area, dragging the slider a bit down, to see greater icons (especially photos, but also other files), then I get again the HUGE icons...

I googled to check if someone found it as weird as I do.
There is a thread in Apple Communities where it seems that confirms my thought:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2492638?start=0&tstart=0

Anyway, does anybody know if this can be fixed somehow?

Answer (score 1):

The preference is stored in the `FlowViewHeight` key. Something like `defaults write com.apple.finder FlowViewHeight -int 180` only changes it temporarily, but you could run the command every minute by running `EDITOR=nano crontab -e` and adding a line like this:

```
* * * * * defaults write com.apple.finder FlowViewHeight -int 180
```

Or just [make the default size of Finder windows bigger](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72273).